# How to scale a css shape-outside based on an image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am experimenting with CSS's `shape-outside` property using an image, but at least in Safari, the resulting shape is always based on the original image size and I don't see any way of actually scaling the image based on the box size, which would be necessary for a truly responsive design (not to mention making life easier for initial testing purposes).

For example, in this CSS snippet:

```
#shapetest {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('some-image.png');
    shape-outside: url('some-image.png');
    background-size: contain;
}
```

while the background is scaled to cover the div, the shape is still at the original size of `some-image.png`, which isn't unexpected. However, I'd really like to be able to scale the shape to fit within the box, without having to generate multiple renditions of the shape.

Am I missing some sort of scaling function for `shape-outside`? The resources I can find on this indicate that the scaling factor for a `shape-outside` image isn't actually specified just yet, making this somewhat less useful for designs where the object might scale based on a viewport-relative size, for example.

EDIT: In particular I want to be able to specify the *height* of the image (and have the width respond accordingly). The initial answer on this question worked well with a specified width, but the following attempt at reproducing this doesn't work, as the specified height of the `div` flows the text downward, and setting the `div` to `float:left` causes its own box to supercede the shape in the flow:

```css
div.inset {
    height: 1.5in;
}

div.inset img {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    shape-outside: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="inset"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png"></div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum ornare fermentum. Praesent at leo volutpat, tempus eros vel, tempus diam. Morbi in viverra tortor. Etiam lobortis cursus elementum. Mauris eget lectus eget dolor posuere varius vitae a mi. Praesent nec commodo tellus. Nam facilisis tincidunt risus ac consequat. Nam arcu tellus, aliquam sodales metus vel, mollis porta purus. Suspendisse sagittis hendrerit dolor, sit amet accumsan libero cursus sit amet. Duis non fringilla ante. Vestibulum vestibulum scelerisque leo, sit amet elementum mauris. Donec eget dui mollis, venenatis dui non, viverra urna. Nam molestie, felis ut mollis ultricies, erat turpis ullamcorper sem, nec eleifend quam ex ac eros. Praesent sodales ligula quis dui maximus fermentum. Suspendisse tempor luctus elit.
```

Doing it with a specified width and computed height works fine, however:

```css
div.inset {
    width: 1.5in;
}

div.inset img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    shape-outside: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="inset"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png"></div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum ornare fermentum. Praesent at leo volutpat, tempus eros vel, tempus diam. Morbi in viverra tortor. Etiam lobortis cursus elementum. Mauris eget lectus eget dolor posuere varius vitae a mi. Praesent nec commodo tellus. Nam facilisis tincidunt risus ac consequat. Nam arcu tellus, aliquam sodales metus vel, mollis porta purus. Suspendisse sagittis hendrerit dolor, sit amet accumsan libero cursus sit amet. Duis non fringilla ante. Vestibulum vestibulum scelerisque leo, sit amet elementum mauris. Donec eget dui mollis, venenatis dui non, viverra urna. Nam molestie, felis ut mollis ultricies, erat turpis ullamcorper sem, nec eleifend quam ex ac eros. Praesent sodales ligula quis dui maximus fermentum. Suspendisse tempor luctus elit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/#shapes-from-image) say the following:

> The shape is computed to be the path or paths that enclose the area(s) where the opacity of the specified image is greater than the shape-image-threshold value. [...]
>
> The image is sized and positioned as if it were a replaced element whose specified width and height are the same as the element’s used content box size.

So using the `background-size` property doesn't change anything to the element's content box size. Using the actual image element instead should make the computed shape respond to the current content box size of the image. You can now simply set a relative unit like `%` for the `width` of the image element to achieve responsiveness.

Here is a working example. You can change the width of the container and the width of the image as well as its shape should respond to the changing container width:

```css
.shape {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  shape-outside: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png);
}

.container {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="shape" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png" />
</div>
```

This approach relies on a width-only div not having a height of its own, however. But this solution also works:

```css
img.inset {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 1.5in;
    shape-outside: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png');
}
```

```html
<img class="inset"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg/243px-Svg_example3.svg.png">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In rutrum ornare fermentum. Praesent at leo volutpat, tempus eros vel, tempus diam. Morbi in viverra tortor. Etiam lobortis cursus elementum. Mauris eget lectus eget dolor posuere varius vitae a mi. Praesent nec commodo tellus. Nam facilisis tincidunt risus ac consequat. Nam arcu tellus, aliquam sodales metus vel, mollis porta purus. Suspendisse sagittis hendrerit dolor, sit amet accumsan libero cursus sit amet. Duis non fringilla ante. Vestibulum vestibulum scelerisque leo, sit amet elementum mauris. Donec eget dui mollis, venenatis dui non, viverra urna. Nam molestie, felis ut mollis ultricies, erat turpis ullamcorper sem, nec eleifend quam ex ac eros. Praesent sodales ligula quis dui maximus fermentum. Suspendisse tempor luctus elit.
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! It doesn't quite cover the specific use case I'm trying for here but it's a great pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Hm, although I'm having trouble getting my text to actually flow around it correctly - the element inspector in Safari is showing the shape as correct but text is still flowing around the outer box, although it works fine in your example. This is the case whether I'm setting the container width or height (and I'm not floating the container div itself)

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem with a stack snippet in your question? Or in a new question?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to get a minimum reproduction of the problem

Comment: Edits made. I had originally gone with an `<img>` based approach (rather than a background image) FWIW, but having just the `img` on its own didn't work either.

Comment: haha but I just found a solution that works for what I was trying to do. I'll suggest an edit to your post accordingly :)